# Convert org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord to org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, mapr, spark-avro

I have list of `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord`, `avro schema`using this we need to create `dataframe` with the help of `SQLContext` API, to create `dataframe` it needs `RDD` of `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` and `avro schema`. Pre-requisite to create DF is we should have RDD of org.apache.spark.sql.Row and it can be achieved using below code but some how it is not working and giving error, sample code.

```
 1. Convert GenericRecord to Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
    import org.apache.avro.Schema
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
    def convertGenericRecordToRow(genericRecords: Seq[GenericRecord], avroSchema: Schema, schemaType: StructType): Seq[Row] =
    {
      val fields = avroSchema.getFields
      var rows = new Seq[Row]
      for (avroRecord <- genericRecords) {
        var avroFieldsSeq = Seq[Any]();
        for (i <- 0 to fields.size - 1) {
          avroFieldsSeq = avroFieldsSeq :+avroRecord.get(fields.get(i).name)
        }
        val avroFieldArr = avroFieldsSeq.toArray
        val genericRow = new GenericRowWithSchema(avroFieldArr, schemaType)
        rows = rows :+ genericRow
      }
      return rows;
    }

2. Convert `Avro schema` to `Structtype`
   Use `com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters -> toSqlType` function , it will convert avro schema to StructType

3. Create `Dataframe` using `SQLContext`
   val rowSeq= convertGenericRecordToRow(genericRecords, avroSchema, schemaType)
   val rowRdd = sc.parallelize(rowSeq, 1)
   val finalDF =sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD,structType)
```

But it is throwing an error at creation of `DataFrame`. Can someone please help me what is wrong in above code. Apart from this if someone has different logic for converting and creation of `dataframe`.

Whenever I will invoke any action on Dataframe, it will execute DAG and try to create DF object but in this it is failing with below exception as

```
 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
 Error :Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, hdpoc-c01-r06-01, executor 1): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 1
                        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
                        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
```

After this I am trying to give correct version jar in jar parameter of spark submit and with other parameter as  --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true
but now it is failing with MapR as

```
ERROR CLDBRpcCommonUtils: Exception during init
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetClusterOption(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)
                    at com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetClusterOption(Native Method)
                    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.init(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:163)
                    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<init>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:73)
                    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<clinit>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:63)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:69)
                    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

We are using MapR distribution and after class path change in spark-submit, it is failing with above exception.

Can someone please help here or my basic need it to convert Avro GenericRecord into Spark Row so i can create Dataframe with it, please help
Thanks.

Comment: Whats the exact error? and please update question with genericRecords sample, avroSchema.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan      Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, hdpoc-c01-r03-01, executor 2): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 1
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)

Comment: the error looks like version error between the source of streaming data and the converting code in your local. You will have to use the same version of FastDateFormat package that the source is using. And Please update the error in the question so that others can help you too.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have updated everything in the question, Is there any other way to convert GenericRecord to Spark row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating dataframe from RDD[GenericRecord] there are few steps

1. First need to convert org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord into org.apache.spark.sql.Row

> Use com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters.createConverterToSQL(
>   sourceAvroSchema: Schema,targetSqlType: DataType)

this is private method in spark-avro 3.2 version. If we are having same or less than 3.2 then copy this method into your own util class and use it else directly use it.

2. Create Dataframe from collection of Row (rowSeq).

> val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(rowSeq,numParition) val
>   dataframe = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schemaType)

This resolves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps somebody coming a bit later to the game.

Since `spark-avro` is deprecated and now integrated in Spark, there is a different way this can be accomplished.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

...

val avroSchema = data.head.getSchema
val sparkTypes = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(avroSchema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
val converter = new AvroDeserializer(avroSchema, sparkTypes)
val enconder = RowEncoder.apply(sparkTypes).resolveAndBind()

val rows = data.map { record =>
    enconder.fromRow(converter.deserialize(record).asInstanceOf[InternalRow])
}

val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), sparkTypes)
```

Comment: how can we do it spark 3.0.1 version

Comment: Now org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroDeserializer class is private in spark 3, @Grbinho can you suggest other way we can do the same thing in spark 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help. In the first part you can find how convert from GenericRecord to Row

[How to convert RDD[GenericRecord] to dataframe in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264701/how-to-convert-rddgenericrecord-to-dataframe-in-scala/47267060#47267060)

Comment: Actually I tried explained in link earlier but was not getting correct dataframe. First we need to change RDD[GenericRecord] to RDD[Row] and then you can create data frame.

Comment: please see answer below.