# How to convert RDD[GenericRecord] to dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I get tweets from kafka topic with Avro (serializer and deserializer).
Then i create a spark consumer which extracts tweets in Dstream of RDD[GenericRecord].
Now i want to convert each rdd to a dataframe to analyse these tweets via SQL.
Any solution to convert RDD[GenericRecord] to dataframe please ?

Comment: can you  update with some sample data of RDD[GenericRecord] by doing foreach(println)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent some time trying to make this work (specially how deserialize the data properly but it looks like you already cover this)  ... UPDATED

```
  //Define function to convert from GenericRecord to Row
  def genericRecordToRow(record: GenericRecord, sqlType : SchemaConverters.SchemaType): Row = {
    val objectArray = new Array[Any](record.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord].getSchema.getFields.size)
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    for (field <- record.getSchema.getFields) {
      objectArray(field.pos) = record.get(field.pos)
    }

    new GenericRowWithSchema(objectArray, sqlType.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
  }

//Inside your stream foreachRDD
val yourGenericRecordRDD = ... 
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(...) // your schema
val sqlType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(new Schema.Parser().parse(strSchema))

var rowRDD = yourGeneircRecordRDD.map(record => genericRecordToRow(record, sqlType))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD , sqlType.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
```

As you see, I am using a SchemaConverter to get the dataframe structure from the schema that you used to deserialize (this could be more painful with schema registry). For this you need the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

you will need to change your spark version depending on yours.

UPDATE: the code above only works for **flat** avro schemas.

For **nested** structures I used something different. You can copy the  class [SchemaConverters](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala), it has to be inside of `com.databricks.spark.avro` (it uses some protected classes from the databricks package) or you can try to use the [spark-bigquery](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/spotify/spark-bigquery/0.1.0-s_2.11) dependency.  The class will not be accessible by default, so you will need to create a class inside a package `com.databricks.spark.avro` to access the factory method.

```
package com.databricks.spark.avro

import com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters.createConverterToSQL
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

class SchemaConverterUtils {

  def converterSql(schema : Schema, sqlType : StructType) = {
    createConverterToSQL(schema, sqlType)
  }

}
```

After that you should be able to convert the data like

```
val schema = .. // your schema
val sqlType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
....
//inside foreach RDD
var genericRecordRDD = deserializeAvroData(rdd)
/// 
var converter = SchemaConverterUtils.converterSql(schema, sqlType)
... 
val rowRdd = genericRecordRDD.flatMap(record => {
        Try(converter(record).asInstanceOf[Row]).toOption
      })
//To DataFrame
 val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, sqlType)
```

Comment: the method createDataFrame need as arguments RDD[ROW] and structType but i have in my case createDataFramei have  RDD[GenericRecord]

Comment: yw! just make sure that you review my last  change.. I was missing pass the values to the objectArray object before create the raw

Answer (score 0):

A combination of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48828303/5957143 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47267060/5957143 works for me.

I used the following to create MySchemaConversions

```
package com.databricks.spark.avro

import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType

object MySchemaConversions {
  def createConverterToSQL(avroSchema: Schema, sparkSchema: DataType): (GenericRecord) => Row =
    SchemaConverters.createConverterToSQL(avroSchema, sparkSchema).asInstanceOf[(GenericRecord) => Row]
}
```

And then I used

```
val myAvroType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType
val myAvroRecordConverter = MySchemaConversions.createConverterToSQL(schema, myAvroType)
```

// unionedResultRdd is unionRDD[GenericRecord]

```
var rowRDD = unionedResultRdd.map(record => MyObject.myConverter(record, myAvroRecordConverter))
 val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD , myAvroType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
```

The advantage of having myConverter in the object MyObject is that you will not encounter serialization issues (java.io.NotSerializableException).

```
object MyObject{
    def myConverter(record: GenericRecord,
        myAvroRecordConverter: (GenericRecord) => Row): Row =
            myAvroRecordConverter.apply(record)
}
```

Comment: how we will do it spark 3.0.1 version

Answer (score -1):

Even though something like this may help you,

```
val stream = ...

val dfStream = stream.transform(rdd:RDD[GenericRecord]=>{
     val df = rdd.map(_.toSeq)
              .map(seq=> Row.fromSeq(seq))
              .toDF(col1,col2, ....)

     df
})
```

I'd like to suggest you an alternate approach. With Spark 2.x you can skip the whole process of creating `DStreams`. Instead, you can do something like this with structured streaming,

```
val df = ss.readStream
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .load("/path/to/files")
```

This will give you a single dataframe which you can directly query. Here, `ss` is the instance of spark session. `/path/to/files` is the place where all your avro files are being dumped from kafka.

**PS:** You may need to import `spark-avro`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "4.0.0"
```

Hope this helped. Cheers

Comment: I do not have files , i want to convert RDD[GenericRecord] to dataframe

Answer (score -3):

You can use createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType), which is available in the SQLContext object. Example for converting an RDD of an old DataFrame:

```
import sqlContext.implicits.
val rdd = oldDF.rdd
val newDF = oldDF.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, oldDF.schema)
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly set any schema column. We reuse the old DF's schema, which is of StructType class and can be easily extended. However, this approach sometimes is not possible, and in some cases can be less efficient than the first one.

Comment: I don't have an old dataframe. I have just  RDD[GenericRecord]

Comment: You create your schema .// Example : val innerSchema =
    StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("value", StringType),
        StructField("count", LongType)
      )
    )