# Convert GenericRecord to DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I have a requirement in streaming where I have to convert the GenericRecord to DatFrame so that I can use EXPLODE and other features available in DF. So first, am looking at how to convert GenericRecord to DF.

I have checked the below URL which helps in converting the record to DF. But am not able to understand how to add the class SchemaConverterUtils to avro object.

[How to convert RDD[GenericRecord] to dataframe in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264701/how-to-convert-rddgenericrecord-to-dataframe-in-scala)

Its giving me read-only file when I try to edit. Am new to scala/java. Could you please help me understand how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Answer (score 1):

About that post, the **spark-avro** library is deprecated by DataBricks and is donated to Spark.

**ABRiS** library provides a UDF to convert a column of `Array[Byte]` to a column of complex type and eventually to a *DataFrame*.

In your case, you should first couple of transformations.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_avro
import za.co.absa.abris.examples.data.generation.AvroDataUtils

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
// read data into an RDD of GenericRecord called "genericRecordRdd"
// Have your schema in string format in a variable called "stringSchema"
import spark.implicits._
val domainDF: DataFrame = genericRecordRdd
        .map(AvroDataUtils.recordToBytes)
        .toDF("value")
        .select(from_avro(col("value"), stringSchema) as 'data).select("data.*")
```

The `AvroDataUtils.recordToBytes` is part of ABRiS library that converts a `GenericRecord` object to `Array[Byte]`. Then you create a `DataFrame` with only one column and it is called `"value"`. At this moment, you are ready to use `from_avro` UDF. Following the documentation on the website, you do have other options but from your description, I thought this would be the closest.

Comment: can we convert the generic record to spark row in spark 3.0.1 using abris library?