# Expressing spark `StructType` in avro schema

Tags: apache-spark, avro, parquet

How would you describe spark `StructType` data type in an avro schema? I am generating a parquet file, the format of which is described in an avro schema. This file is then loaded from S3 into spark. There is an `array` and `map` data types but these do not correspond to the `StructType`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package org.apache.spark.sql.avro (Spark 2.4) you can convert sparkSQL schemas to avro schemas and viceversa.

You can try this way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters
val sqlType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(avroSchema)
var rowRDD = yourGeneircRecordRDD.map(record => genericRecordToRow(record, sqlType))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, sqlType.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
```

Here you can find more answers too: [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47267060/10135225)